# How to test code which mostly uses external APIs?

Tags: api, unit-testing, testing, integration-testing

I've recently written some code where I found it near impossible to write useful tests.

It's a cronjob which does this:

- fetch users from an external service (AWS cognito)
- checks certain properties of the user by asking internal APIs of our system
- send users mails (AWS SES) according to business logic
- update user properties (AWS cognito)

In total, it's about 100 lines of python. To test this, the usual recommendation seems to be to check the format of the APIs and mock them in tests. I can do this for my "happy path", but I don't really have a way to know how data will be transmitted in all cases and failure modes since there are so many external services involved.

I would expect failures of this code mostly if it receives some unexpected piece of data, but there's no way to test for this, or is there?

I've done consumer driven contract testing with pact in a larger system, but here I could only employ it against the internal API which is under our control, and the infrastructure necessary for this seems to be too much for such a small script.

Our current approach is to monitor the script for errors and fix it the next day in the office. From the business rules perspective, it's not a problem if the script doesn't run for a few days. Do you think that this is the best approach here?

How would you test this?

Answer (score 0):

tldr; Depending on resources, priorities and criticality solution with monitoring and some unit tests could be a good fit.

---

In such a case I would try to decouple components. It will allow me to test all components independently and simplify final test logic.

Let's consider cronjob from example. Probably pseudo-code will look like the next one:

```py
def main():
    users: List[Users] = fetch_users()
    filtered_users = check_properties(users)

    business_logic_with_sending_emails(filtered_users)
    update_properties(filtered_users)
```

I divided logic on separate functions, and now I can test every function separately (even main)

`fetch_users` responsible for interaction with external system and converting their responses to predefined user models. If any errors occur, `fetch_users` should handle it. Depending on the external system I could test this function with integration tests or unit tests with mocks/stubs. Each option has its own pros and cons. You mention that you have monitoring and functionality is not critical, so unit-tests with mocks/stubs and monitoring will be a good fit. Even if we missed some negative scenario in mock tests and it failed on production, monitoring will catch it, with a separate `fetch_users` function we could localize and reproduce it, and then we could easily extend our tests with this new case.

With `check_properties` we could do the same — test it with integ tests or with mocks/stubs. Main thing here is that we don't need to call `fetch_users`, we can transfer test users directly to `check_properties`. As you mentioned `check_properties` make calls to internal api, so we could use here consumer driven contract testing (if it's already exist), or integ tests or any others tests which guarantee contracts between systems (ie validations by swagger/openapi specs)

`business_logic_with_sending_emails` — probably this function is most important from a business point of view, so we need to cover all business logic with unit (func) tests. Luckily we don't need to make requests (for fetching users) to any real external system, we just transfer test users directly to `business_logic_with_sending_emails`. We even don't need to check real email sending, it's enough to check that we call a function which sending emails (sending real emails we could check in separate integration tests)
With `update_properties` the same story as with `fetch_users`.

And the last one is `main`. While we tested all functions separately it doesn't guarantee that all functions in main were called appropriately. Probably in such a straightforward function as in example pseudo-code there is no need to test it (cause there is no any complex logic), but in complex cases it's good to check "happy path" and few negative. It could be done with mocks or with IoC/DI mechanisms.

Comment: Thanks for this extensive answer. I would also tend towards a solution like this, but it would still require quite some mocking and there would still be runtime errors in case a service sends unexpected data. So there doesn't seem to be a way to get closer to the confidence you can get from testing in a monolith.